# porque me da fatal error la variable de conexion

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Porque no me deja conectarme a la base de datos, si todos los datos de conexion estan bien, el error que me manda es el siguiente:

fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\MGS\registrar_tablas.php:38 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MGS\registrar_tablas.php(38): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO gen...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MGS\registrar_tablas.php on line 38

el archivo de data_base.php es el siguiente:

```
<?php


$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","cris123","mgs");


?>
```

y el de registrar_tablas.php es este:

```
<?php

include('data_base.php');



$personal_salud=$_POST['personal_salud'];
$turno=$_POST['turno'];
$num_empleado=$_POST['#_empleado'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$edad=$_POST['edad'];
$area=$_POST['area'];
$puesto=$_POST['puesto'];
$supervisor=$_POST['supervisor'];
$aparato_sistema=$_POST['aparato_sistema'];
$diagnostico=$_POST['diagnostico'];
$observaciones=$_POST['observacion'];
$medicamento=$_POST['medicamento'];
$fecha=("d-m-Y");





// Create connection
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","cris123","mgs");
// Check connection
if (!$conexion) {
  die("Connection Failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$consulta = "INSERT INTO general(personal_salud, turno, fecha, num_empleado, nombre, edad, area_trabajo, puesto, supervisor, aparato_sistema, diagnostico, observaciones, medicamento)
VALUES ('$personal_salud', '$turno','$fecha', '$num_empleado', '$nombre' '$edad','$area','$puesto','$supervisor','$aparato_sistema','$diagnostico', '$observaciones' ,'$medicamento')";



$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);


if($resultado) {
    header("location:mostrartablas.php");

} else {
    echo"No se pudo registrar";
}
    

 
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion); 
?>
```

la verdad no se en que este fallando

Comment: @DavidJP tiene razón en lo que dice en su respuesta. Pero una fecha mal formateada no produciría este error, aunque te creará una fecha inválida en la tabla si esa columna fuera del tipo `date` o `datetime`, por lo que debes formatearla bien antes de insertar. En cuanto al error en sí mismo, sospecho que tus datos no están en la superglobal `$_POST`, sino en `$_GET` o que alguna de las claves no es correcta. Prueba a colocar un `var_dump($_POST);` y revisa cada clave. Si no muestra nada, pon un `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: Tienes `'$nombre' '$edad'`, te falta una coma entre los dos valores.

Comment: Vista de águila, @Sal, lo miré dos veces y no vi ese error.

Answer (score 0):

El conteo de registros del `INSERT` lo he comprobado y me cuadra:

```
INSERT INTO general(
        personal_salud, turno, fecha, num_empleado,
        nombre, edad, area_trabajo,
        puesto, supervisor, aparato_sistema,
        diagnostico, observaciones, medicamento
    ) VALUES (
        '$personal_salud', '$turno','$fecha', '$num_empleado',
        '$nombre' '$edad','$area',
        '$puesto','$supervisor','$aparato_sistema',
        '$diagnostico', '$observaciones','$medicamento'
    );
```

Por lo que me inclino a pensar en el formato de fecha que usas en:

```
$fecha=("d-m-Y");
```

Que debería ser `$fecha=("Y-m-d");` o, incluso mejor, usar directamente un `NOW()` en el SQL, quedando la línea:

```
'$personal_salud', '$turno','$fecha', '$num_empleado',
```

Como:

```
'$personal_salud', '$turno', NOW(), '$num_empleado',
```

Y, como última recomendación, no uses el método `query()` sino una consulta preparada con los métodos `prepare()`, `bind_result()`, `execute()` y `close()`. Así evitarás una vulnerabilidad por inyección de código.

Answer (score 0):

Como te han comentado no es nada recomendable hacer el insert directamente con las variables post ya que si estas variables tuviesen una comilla simple te romperían la query o incluso como te han comentado podrían acceder a tu base de datos. El error que te da, da a entender que   al hacer el insert no coinciden los parámetros con los valores, cosa que podria ser si alguno de ellos tuviese comilla simple y te rompiese la query

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).